# How to edit the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to edit the `GridView` without involving the database

```
protected void myGridView_RowUpdating(object sender,GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string reg = (myGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)myGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox name = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
    TextBox email = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];

    myGridView.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGird();
}
```

this my bindgrid fucntion:

```
protected void BindGird() 
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["myCart"]; 
    this.myGridView.DataSource = dt; this.myGridView.DataBind(); 
}
```

and this is the row editing event

```
protected void myGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) 
{ 
    myGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; BindGird(); 
}
```

Comment: protected void BindGird()
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["myCart"];
            this.myGridView.DataSource = dt;
            this.myGridView.DataBind();
        }
       this my bindgrid fucntion

Comment: protected void myGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            myGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindGird();
            
        }
and it is row editing event.. please help me out.